# Display column data based from foreign id on another table

Tags: php, sql, eloquent, laravel-7

I want to display kategori_name from kategori table based on id_kategori from produks tabel to my view but still getting error using either Eloquent or Query Builder

This is my Product migration

```
Schema::create('produks', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('product_name');
    $table->foreignId('id_kategori')->references('id')->on('kategoris');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

this is the category migration

```
Schema::create('kategoris', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('kategori_name');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

this is my attempt:

```
$joinkategori = DB::table('produks')->where('id_kategori')->where(Kategori::select('kategori_name')->first());
return view('admin/createproduk', compact('joinkategori'));
```

but still getting error as such

> Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection::$nama_kategori (View: D:\oricraft\resources\views\admin\createproduk.blade.php)

how do I achieve this using eloquent or query builder? thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create two models

`Product` for `produks`

`Kategori` for `kategoris` (as per question this already created )

so in Product model add relationship

```
public function category(){

  return $this->belongTo(Kategori::class,'id_kategori','id')
}
```

then n query

```
$joinkategori =Product::with('category')->get()
```

or

```
$joinkategori =Product::with('category')->has('category')->get()
```

Comment: the result is just empty sir, this is the foreach on view:
` @foreach($joinkategori as $kategori)
  <td>{{$kategori -> nama_kategori}}</td>
   @endforeach`

Comment: where is the nama_kategori coumn in datatable table ?

Comment: look like it should be {{$kategori ->category->kategori_name}}

Comment: that was a typo but then it works perfectly, thank you.